# How to add table widget in a QtoolBox item?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm working in a simple gui with a QtoolBox can increase the item dynamically (with button "add item"). I need to add, for each item, a new widget like table (for example TableView class) but I can't understand how can I do it. Could anybody help me? (follow the code I wrote until now)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

data = {'col1':['1','2','3','4'],
        'col2':['1','2','1','3'],
        'col3':['1','1','2','1']}


class TableView(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, *args):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.data = data
        self.setData()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
 
    def setData(self): 
        horHeaders = []
        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.data.keys())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.numAddWidget = 1
        self.initUi()
        # Add toolbar and items
        
    def initUi(self):
        self.add_button = QPushButton("Add Widget")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.add_button, 0, 0)
        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.addPage)
        self.toolbox = QToolBox()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.toolbox, 1, 0)
        
    def addPage(self):
        self.numAddWidget += 1
        label = QLabel()
        a=self.toolbox.addItem(label, "item {}".format(self.numAddWidget))
        self.table=TableView(data, 4, 3)
        self.toolbox.addWidget(self.table)
        print(a)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `addWidget`? QToolBox has no such function, you can find all available function in [its documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbox.html). Change to `self.toolbox.addItem(self.table, "table")`, as you did in the previous case with the label.

Comment: Thank you for your very usefull  help! 
With  '''self.toolbox.addItem(self.table, "table")''' I can add an item with table, but how can add even a botton ora other widget together?

Comment: Please, can you explain yourself better? What does "add even a botton ora other widget" mean?

Comment: Excuse me. I intended: "add a button or other widget". However I think solved my problem: I've build a new class with table and button (and other widget) and add it at run time. It was more simple than I thought. Thank you.